# When to use org.springframework.context.event.EventListener and org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to learn the Event-driven/Message-Driven concepts from the spring cloud, I came across the two annotations @EventListener and @StreamListener. Could some guide me to understand the basic differences between these two? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with spring-cloud-stream we are moving away from annotation-based configuration model and embracing convention-over configuration functional model.
So for example, below is a fully functioning spring-cloud-stream app that will receive and process message.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggingConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoggingConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> log() {
        return value -> {
            System.out.println("Received: " + value);
        };
    }
}
```

You can get more details [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_quick_start)

I would also recommend to read these two posts that provide a bit of history and motivation as to why we are moving away from `@StreamListener` and into simpler functional programming model.

1. https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified
2. https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive

Hope that helps

Comment: And `@EventListener ` has nothing to do with Stream - it is used to receive `ApplicationEvent`s published by many components.